# Exchange Web Services - Organizer Property

Tags: c#, exchange-server, exchangewebservices

I am using Exchange Web Services trying to find the Organizer of the meeting's email address

I have tried using

```
 Appoint.Organizer.Address
```

but some of the properties are null (see image).

How do I get the email address of the organizer?

Link to image (sorry not enough rep to embed)

https://i.stack.imgur.com/wSv2r.png

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What operation are you using ? If you have just used FindItems then that's what you would expected because only the displayName of the Sender (which is the Organizer) is returned with FindItems. To get the Address property populated you would need to do a GetItem (or Load in the Managed API).Or if you really want to save a call you could try using the PidTagSenderSmtpAddress extended property http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/jj713594(v=office.15).aspx

Cheers
Glen

Comment: Hi Glen, thanks - I solved this without your help but your solution was the right answer :)

Answer (score 0):

Do you know how this meeting came into the mailbox? Was it sent from a sender outside of Exchange, or another mailbox in that Exchange organization? What version of Exchange? Also how are you binding to the appointment? It would be good to see that code. I've tried this with a few meetings here and they all have the Address property populated. Your screenshot shows a MailboxType field of "OneOff", and I'm not sure off the top of my head how to make that happen.

Typically "OneOff" refers to a recipient that couldn't be resolved. In this case, you might try taking the information that is present (in this case the display name) and calling [ResolveName](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd635548(v=exchg.80).aspx) to see if you can get the address that way.