# Get the Organizer email address from Outlook Exchange API (C#)

Tags: c#, exchange-server, exchangewebservices

so far using the Microsoft Exchange API I have managed to retrieve the Subject, Location, Start Date/Time & End Date/Time, but I am having difficulty getting the Organizers name or email... does anyone have any idea how to get it?

this is an example of the code that retrieves the information:

```
       var entries=GetCalendar();

        foreach (var en in entries)
        {
            var row = new TableRow();

            var Subject = new TableCell();
            var Location = new TableCell();

            Subject.Text = en.Subject;
            Location.Text = en.Location;

            //row.Cells.Add(Subject);
            //row.Cells.Add(Location);

            Table1.Rows.Add(row);
        }
```

and hers is the method to call public class im calling to get the desired information:

```
 public List<Appointment> GetCalendar()
        {
            var LIST= ExchangeServerAPI.ExchangeCalendars.GetCalendar("username", "password", "domain",
                "exchange web address", new DateTime(2015, 1, 1), new DateTime(2015, 1, 31),
                max entries to load (100));

             return LIST;
        }
```

I am using this to populate a table in a C# ASP.Net application...

and here is an image of the error (basically saying it cant retrieve the desired information)

[image]

and this should be retrieveing the name but it doesn't...

```
  public string Organizer
    {
      get
      {
          return (string)this.PropertyBag[AppointmentSchema.Organizer.Name];
      }
        set
        {
            this.PropertyBag[AppointmentSchema.Organizer.Name] = (object)value;
        }
    }
```

Scenario: the user adds in an Appointment to there calendar and the ASP.Net application should be able to retrieve everything added which is associated to the username which is called above. this will display everything in a table format. this is all that I require for now

link to Visual Studio file: https://www.dropbox.com/s/nglbiynvs5js5lb/ExchangeServerAPI.zip?dl=0

Comment: Is this what you're looking for?
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25379871/exchange-web-services-organizer-property

Comment: yes but that doesn't actually have a definitive answer, the url links contained within don't really help a great deal, thanks for looking though

Comment: I'm not familiar with this ExchangeServerAPI.ExchangeCalendars API. Do you have a link? It sounds like it's probably using EWS under the hood, and you need to somehow tell it to load the Organizer property when it does the FindItems request.

Comment: added the project folder as a zip onto dropbox so you can have a look at the full thing